# How to find the difference between two UNIX timestamps in minutes PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to find the difference between the two UNIX timestamps in minutes in php.

I wrote such a code:

```
$current_time = 1474719107000;
$start_time = 1474716600000;
$difference = $current_time - $start_time;
echo $difference/60;
```

The difference should be almost 40 mins. But I am getting a value of 41783.333333333. Not sure what's my mistake.

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Those are not Unix timestamps. You could have checked that with date('r', $current_time);. They look like Javascript timestamps - measured in milliseconds, using same datum as Unix timestamps (which are measured in seconds)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your two timestamps are in **milliseconds.** You need to further divide them by 1000.

```
echo $difference/60/1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're aware of that but those are not PHP timestamps; PHP timestamps (and Unix timestamps as well) are represented in seconds and the ones you have there seem to be milliseconds. Are those from Javascript?

Anyway, if you want to get a result in minutes using those values, you need to divide milliseconds by 1000 (to get seconds) and then divide again by 60 (to get minutes).

This should work:

```
$current_time = 1474719107000;
$start_time = 1474716600000;
$difference = $current_time - $start_time;
echo $difference / 1000 / 60;
```